# how to pass string between 2 viewControllers?

Tags: swift, swift3, textview

```
var textToPass: String = ""

@IBAction func modalAction(_ sender: Any) {

        textToPass = textView.text
        print(textToPass)

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController {

            present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            secondVC.textObject = textToPass  // textObject = String?
}
```

Hello.
I have no idea why secondVC.textObject is nil in this code. 
Please teach me.

Answer (score 0):

First assign value to textObject and then present the viewController :

```
if let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController {
        secondVC.textObject = textToPass 
        present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```